# Facebook link sharing through API c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to share post on my facebook wall but i am getting the error. 
I am using the facebook nuget for the same.

this is my code

```
 Facebook.FacebookClient facebookClient = new 
 Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);

 dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
 messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
 //messagePost.picture = "[A_PICTURE]";
 //messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
 //messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
 //messagePost.caption = "my caption"; 
 messagePost.message = message;
 //messagePost.description = "my description";

 var result = facebookClient.Post("/me/feed", messagePost);
```

I am getting this error.

> (OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.